# echo js using php to append more options to select input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay so I'm having that JS :

```
 <script>
    $('#building').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getunits.php',
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            data:{
                building: selectedValue,
            },

            success: function (result) {

                var e = document.getElementById('div1');
                e.innerHTML = result;
                eval(document.getElementById('runscript').innerHTML);

            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="div1">
</div>
```

And that in the PHP :

```
$selectunits = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `units` WHERE `building`='".$building."'");
echo '<script type="text/javascript" id="runscript">';
while($rowunits = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectunits))
{
    //echo '<option value="'.$rowunits["ID"].'">'.$rowunits["unit_number"].'</option>';
    echo '$("#unit").append("<option value="'.$rowunits["ID"].'">'.$rowunits["unit_number"].'</option>");';
}
echo'</\script>';
```

All I'm trying to do is after I select from the first select, an Ajax goes to that URL and fills up the 2nd select with different data. So what I was able to do is do a loop in the PHP to create the required JS to fill up.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: I can only suspect, that your code does not work, because the browser already built the DOM and does not reparse the added <script> tag. The more ajaxy way to accomplish, what you want to do, is for the php to return json data describing the new elements and then inserting those elements using the jquery success function

Comment: Daniel may you please show me example, I never tried json data,\

Comment: and Alex, I already have mysqli_real_escape_string to the $_POST variable

Comment: You should filter your result, but not document for "runscript" id. One of the solutions is - use json response type if possible.

Comment: This is not the right way to pass data to the page. All you need is to echo JSON (using `json_encode()`), which can be parsed by your AJAX success/done callback.